# logname: no login name

Tags: users, terminal-emulator, coreutils, lxterminal

I am trying to understand the differences between `logname` and `LOGNAME` from [Difference between logname and $LOGNAME](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268378/difference-between-logname-and-logname) and https://askubuntu.com/questions/490620/difference-between-logname-and-logname

On Lubuntu 18.04, why did I get `logname: no login name`?

```
t@ocean:/t/t/bkg$ echo $LOGNAME
t
t@ocean:/t/t/bkg$ logname
logname: no login name
t@ocean:/t/t/bkg$ su t
Password: 
t@ocean:/t/t/bkg$ logname
logname: no login name
$ echo $?
1
t@ocean:/t/t/bkg$ cat /var/run/utmp
~~~reboot4.15.0-22-generic��[8Jtty1tty1LOGINJ��[�!�tty7:0t:0��[��5~~~runlevel4.15.0-22-generic��[

t@ocean:/t/t/bkg$ sudo su
[sudo] password for t: 
root@ocean:/tmp/test/bkg# logname
logname: no login name
root@ocean:/tmp/test/bkg# echo $LOGNAME
root
```

What is `logname` supposed to output?
Thanks.

From `man logname`:

> logname - print user´s login name
>
> Print the name of the current user.

---

To address the comments:

```
$ cat /proc/self/loginuid
4294967295

t@ocean:/t/t/bkg$ grep ":$(id -u):" /etc/passwd
t:x:1000:1000:t,,,:/home/t:/bin/bash

t@ocean:/t/t/bkg$ tty
/dev/pts/8
t@ocean:/t/t/bkg$ w
 17:52:08 up 5 days,  6:28,  1 user,  load average: 0.39, 0.29, 0.28
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
t        tty7     :0               Wed11    5days  1:47m  6.33s /usr/bin/lxsession -s Lubuntu -e LXDE
```

Mark suspected the cause is that my `lxterminal` doesn't  add an entry to utmp.

Pandya: Oh. Seems [a bug](https://askubuntu.com/q/424237/256099) with entry as you've concluded.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78232/discussion-on-question-by-tim-logname-no-login-name).

Comment: Moving the helpful comments into a chatroom, which will disappear eventually, is very unfortunate. I have to manually save some comments from the chatroom.

Comment: If the comments are useful, they should be moved to the question or answer they are commenting upon. Comments are designed to be ephemeral and are not the place to have discussions.

Comment: Yet I had to copy others' comments into my question. I am on the side with what this user said in his profile https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/21167/zwol on this matter

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Nevertheless, comments are not for discussion and we really don't want useful information buried in long commet threads. That's what forums are for.

Comment: I had to copy **others'** comments into my question

Comment: The policy saying comments are not for extended discussion is an incorrect and harmful policy.  The discussion of a question or answer belongs _with_ the question or answer, i.e. in the comments. I have refused to cooperate with this policy for years and I advise you to do the same, Tim. @terdon

Comment: @zwol I feel the same. How did you find this post out? Thank you.