# What is the significance of $(logname)?

Tags: environment-variables

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "$(logname) ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/$(logname)' & sudo chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d/$(logname)
```

I use the above one-liner to allow the current user to execute sudo without a password, on remotely connected hosts.

But what exactly is `$(logname)`?

On a local machine, `echo $(logname)` returns nothing, while `echo $LOGNAME` does, so it's not the environmental variable, although I have never seen the value to be any different on remote machines.

Also, are there any other similar `$(foo)` variables (or whatever they are called)?

Comment: It appears that `echo $(logname)` is in fact different to `echo $LOGNAME` on remote hosts when `su`'d into another account.

Comment: This look strange to me, you need sudo right (at least with password prompt) to execute `sudo` in first place.

Comment: Dupe https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268378/difference-between-logname-and-logname . If command logname doesn't work on your 'local machine' it isn't POSIX-compliant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[logname(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/logname) is a command that will return the login name of the current user.
 `$( ... )` is the syntax for [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) which is saying "substitute the output of the command here"

So if your user is `foo` you are executing:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "foo ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/foo' & sudo chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d/foo
```